# Can intermediate calculation with unsigned type be negative?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Two questions on the code below:

1. *Is it allowed to intermediate values on `unsigned` type to "store" negative values?* Formally, both types of operands have type unsigned and the result it unsigned, so this should be prohibited, but it could be possible depending on the answer on the question (2).
2. *Is unsigned subtraction "reversible" by adding the same value?*. As I know the formats to store signed and unsigned values, if we do **(a-b)+b** this always gives **a**, even if **a < b** and if format is unsigned; although I can imagine format that will violate this rule, since this behaviour is not defined. So, the question is, do current standards for C++ and unsigned data storage/manipulation **guarantee** **(a-b)+b** == **a** or not?

I will be thankful for the answer with the references to the respective standard items.

To put in a nutshell: is code below correct and should/might work?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int u2=2;
    unsigned int u3=3;
    unsigned int u5=5;
    
    unsigned int res = (u2-u3)+u5;

    std::cout << res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zhze6xaa4)

*The cause of the question*
Many years I was used to use `int` for indexing arrays and vectors and this worked fine (although with warnings, of course), but left me safe in terms of indexes calculations when not only intermediate values, but intermediate variables could get negative values. Now, making cleanup on code, I am moving to `std::size_t` and want to make sure that this is safe in these terms.

Comment: Short answer for unsigned arithmetic 1) no 2) yes. Unsigned arithmetic is done *modulo* one more than the highest representable unsigned value. Under that definition 2) is always true.

Comment: `u2-u3` will underflow be a very large positive number number, then `+u5` will overflow and be a small positive number.  Overflow/underflow of unsigned integers is well defined behaviour. See [Arithmetic operators: Overflows](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows)

Comment: Unsigned types are guaranteed to wrap - no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @RichardCritten, so am I got you correctly that the answer on the both questions is "yes" and I could use such math in my programs?

Comment: @DamirTenishev _"...Is it allowed to intermediate values on unsigned type to have negative values? ..."_ __no__ it overflows to a large positive value ( `mod 2^n` )

Comment: @RichardCritten, so, either I formulated question incorrectly or your answer contradicts to answer from *user253751*. I get his answer as "yes" and "everything is fine here" and your answer as "no, this is wrong code". So, what's the correct answer?

Comment: No contradictions the expression in the question has well defined behaviour.   What is not correct is the quoted part above _"...unsigned type to have negative values..."_ this is by definition impossible.  What happens in the expression is first underflow and then overflow (the intermediate values always being positive) which with the above example happen to cancel each other out.

Comment: To present the actual numbers: assuming `int` is 32-bit on your machine, `u2-u3` is `2 - 3` and the result of that is `4294967295`, then `u2-u3+u5` is `4294967295 + 5` and the result of that is `4`. This is well defined behaviour, you can expect that from every conforming compiler.

Comment: *So, the question is, do current standards for C++ and signed ... guarantee `(a-b)+b == a` or not?* For **signed**, the guarantee has the caveats that there is no underflow or overflow.  If there is underflow or overflow, it's undefined behavior.  Possibly implemented specific well defined behavior, but that's on the shoulders of the implementation, not the standard, and won't generally be portable.

Comment: @RichardCritten, I get your point. Not sure how to better make wording for it. I mean something like "store the value, which could be treated as negative while being stored in unsigned variable". It seems that we are on the same page here, I am just short of wording.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, should I search proves this in C++ standard or somewhere in IEEE for integer signed/unsinged?

Comment: @Eljay, again, maybe I am here with bad wording, but *Richard Critten* answers in terms of  overflow/underflow (with well defined behaviour) and you say there is no underflow or overflow. So, I am still confused here. Others say that this is fine portable code, you say it is not. If it is not, how people use `std::size_t` calculating indexes while intermediate values could be negative in sophisticated cases of indexing, searching, etc.?

Comment: My comment was in the context of your question for **signed** numbers.  Richard Critten was addressing the **unsigned** numbers.  You asked about signed/unsigned, which was a bit of a curve ball since the other parts of your post only focused on **unsigned**.  The standard has different guarantees for them.

Comment: your wording is totally fine. Its not perfectly accurate (eg intermediate results arent "stored" anywhere), but is clear what you are asking. Those arent "answers" btw, its just comments. If your question is really focused on finding the relevant quotes from the standard you can consider to add the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: You can store `2u-7u` in an unsigned and "use it like -5" if you limit yourself to plus and minus. Multiplication, division and modulo will not work expected. `unsigned a=2u-5u; unsigned b=2u-3u;` `a/b` certainly will not give you 3. All these are well defined (no UB) and w.r.t. your other question in the comment you should check C++ standard. No need to go IEEE.

Comment: Since the question is about the result of `u2-u3`, the code ought to do that: `unsigned x = u2 - u3;`.

Comment: @Eljay, I see. My wording introduced some mess here. With "do current standards for C++ and *unsigned/signed* data" I mean "some IEEE standard which covers how integer (int, long, etc.) signed and unsigned data stored, meaning that one standard should cover all such things together, like *IEEE 754* covers all floating point specifics. So, I meant the whole scope of the document, while I am interested in the specific part, namely *unsigned* data and manipulation, although with all this stuff this verges singed data and manipulation. I fixed the wording in the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, I've added the tag. Initially I was in two minds about adding because I was not sure if this is related to language or to integers storage and manipulation. Like *IEEE 754* covers floating point for all hardware and languages and all languages must meet it. So, in case I had question about floats, I would address IEEE, not C++ first. But I am not aware about standard for integers which covers all these Sign–magnitude, Ones' complement, Two's complement and others from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

Comment: @WeijunZhou, thank you. I will try to find in C++ standard. I will be thankful if somebody could pinpoint the place or give a clue for search.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes, the question is, is there a **guarantee** that x+5 will always give 4? As I understood from comments, it is so. I am just looking for exact statement from standard. It is logical, since this is about the interpretation of the same memory, but I never saw a guarantee that if I passed "underflow" with unsigned integer, the subsequent "overflow" will work as expected. It is highly reasonable, it is logical, it is "as it", but what rule, standard or something in my way to implement hardware differently?

Answer (score 3):

If `a` and `b` both have type `unsigned int`, then `(a - b) + b` will always be equal to `a`, even if `b` is greater than `a`.

You might think this means that `a - b` can be negative, but no: what it actually means is if `a < b`, `a - b` will be a positive number, because operations on `unsigned int` are not exactly the same as the real-world mathematical operations that they approximate. Specifically, `a - b` will be 2<sup>*n*</sup> + *a* − *b*, where *n* is the number of bits in an `unsigned int` on your platform.

You might at least think that you can *think* of `a - b` as negative, but . . . well, often you can. If you're only doing additions, subtractions, and/or multiplications, and all of your operands have type `unsigned type` (and you never convert to anything else), and the final result of the true mathematical expression is an integer in the interval [0, 2<sup>*n*</sup>), then the result of the C++ expression will be the `unsigned int` that represents that integer. (The mathematical basis for this is something called [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).) But something like `(double)(a - b)` will not be negative, and something like `(a - b) / c` will be gibberish, because the value that gets divided by `c` is 2<sup>*n*</sup> + *a* − *b* rather than *a* − *b*.

Comment: Thank you. So, are you saying that this has nothing to do with C++ standard and is covered by representation of integer unsigned/signed values on hardware? If so, I understand that it works for modular arithmetic, but is it guaranteed for all possible int number representations from here: [Signed number representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations). There are a lot of them and modular arithmetic covers only basis. My question is what in my way to implement hardware which will break this? What standard will it violate? (to be continued...)

Comment: The way of thoughts as a model is following. Fine, I invent new hardware which after subtraction 2-3 will **process** the result somehow, make some encrypting, caching, mapping, doesn't matter; the key is that it will store the result in a form which after adding to it 5 will just give something absolutely different than 4. Just imagine, as a matter of thought experiment, that I don't make direct subtraction, but make processing, like with quaternions. What standard in my way to do this and broke this code on my platform **in a legal way**? This is the question.

Comment: At the same time, I got the main part of the answer that on most architectures and in most reasonable and practical cases this code is perfectly fine, portable and will work. Thank you, the first part of the puzzle is solved, although I would be happy to see a reference to standard.

Comment: @DamirTenishev • *So, are you saying that this has nothing to do with C++ standard and is covered by representation of integer unsigned/signed values on hardware?*  It has **everything** to do with C++ standard, and **nothing** to do with the representation of integer unsigned/signed values on hardware.  The representation in hardware must conform to the behavior of the C++ abstract machine, as expressed by the executable of the program with the assumption that the code provided to the compiler is not ill-formed (i.e., does not have undefined behavior).

Comment: @Eljay and *ruakh*, let me stress my point and provide a little bit more "realistic" example. Let's say tomorrow I write optimizing compiler which will statically calculate this code. Here is the way of thoughts (2 and 3 are bad for this example, let me use 2 and 4): "Well, 2-4 is not defined in **unsigned** (type of the intermediate result), so **I am not obliged** to provide any specific resulting value, any of possible values would work, so I will put 0 as the result or ((unsigned int)-1) depending on my mood. The result of the program will be 5 or 4 respectively (to be continued...)

Comment: @Eljay and ruakh, (...continue) when the result must be in this case 2-4+5= 3. The key question, what forces me to make **undefined** (negative value in unsigned variable or temporary calculations) thing to be **strictly defined** value and representation? What line of standard say that 2-4 must have *exact* number (doesn't matter which one), but not "any number the developer likes"? The aforementioned math models say how this should be in math, the question is programming is not a math exactly.

Comment: @DamirTenishev • *negative value in unsigned variable or temporary calculations* — that is **not** undefined.  It is well defined in the C++ standard.  Ruakh's answer describes how it will behave.  I am not a language lawyer, so I cannot cite chapter-and-verse of the standard that describes the behavior in standard-ese.

Comment: @Eljay and ruakh, well in this case C++ Standard 3.9.1.4 "*Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.*"  and 5.3.1.8 "*The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2n, where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand.*" are quite close to covering this. Looking for more precise definition.

Comment: You don't need more precise definition. "obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n" is enough for it. The rest are purely mathematical and has nothing to do with the C++ standard. Formally, it's the properly of the modulo ring Zn. The properties are covered in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), section "Basic properties".